# Error using .assign_latitude_longitude: AttributeError: crs attribute is not available

Tags: python, metpy

I am working with the NDFD forecast datasets and would like to assign lat and long within the array to give me the ability to plot the data outside of matplotlib.  My versions are:

python 3.8,metpy 1.0.0,cartopy 0.18.0, xarray 0.16.2, siphon 0.8.0

```
import os.path
import sys
import xarray
from xarray.backends import NetCDF4DataStore
import xarray as xr
import pyproj

from datetime import *

import cartopy.feature as cfeature
#import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import metpy
import siphon
import math

from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
from siphon.radarserver import RadarServer
from siphon.cdmr import Dataset

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
#from awips.dataaccess import DataAccessLayer
%matplotlib inline

gfs_catalog = ('https://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/grib/NCEP/NDFD/NWS/CONUS/CONDUIT/catalog.xml?dataset=grib/NCEP/NDFD/NWS/CONUS/CONDUIT/Best')
cat = TDSCatalog(gfs_catalog)
ncss = cat.datasets[0].subset()
query = ncss.query()
query.time_range(datetime.utcnow(),datetime.utcnow()+timedelta(days=7))
query.accept('netcdf') 
query.variables('Total_precipitation_surface_6_Hour_Accumulation','Total_precipitation_surface_12_Hour_Ac
cumulation_probability_above_0p254')

query.lonlat_box(west=-86.175, east=-86.0, north=39.85, south=39.75)
data = ncss.get_data(query)
ds = xr.open_dataset(NetCDF4DataStore(data))

#This works to return x and y in metpy's custom projection
var = ds.metpy.parse_cf('Total_precipitation_surface_6_Hour_Accumulation')

#This doesn't
var2 = ds.metpy.assign_latitude_longitude(force='False')
```

AttributeError: crs attribute is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assign_latitude_longitude` requires that information about the CRS is available, so that it can properly calculation longitude and latitude from your projected coordinates. This means that you first need to have called `parse_cf()` in some way. In your code above, you save the results of calling `parse_cf('Total_precipitation_surface_6_Hour_Accumulation')` to `var`, but this *does not* modify the original `Dataset` stored in `ds`.

Instead you need to either call it on the variable that *has* had the information parsed as:

```
var = var.metpy.assign_latitude_longitude(force=False)
```

(note `False` rather than `'False'`). You can also use `parse_cf()` and `assign_latitude_longitude()` on the full dataset:

```
ds = ds.metpy.parse_cf()
ds = ds.metpy.assign_latitude_longitude(force=False)
```

Note that this will download the metadata for *all* variables in the latter case.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you so much.  I have a quick follow up question:  My query produces 6 y values and 8 x values, for 48 total grid rainfall values per time step.  The assign_latitude_longitude command produces 48 latitude and longitude values, which I believe is one set of lat and long for each of the 48 rainfall values.  Just want to make sure I am visualizing this right - the 48 lat long values are the center of each rainfall grid?

Comment: The 48 lat/lon values correspond to the full set of pairs of the original x,y values (the "outer product"). The original x,y pairs are transformed to lat/lon pairs based on the projection metadata. They are likely grid center points, but that's really controlled by what the original x,y values represent.

Comment: Also, if this solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted!